# Angular14 configurations.production.fileReplacements with module.ts problem

Tags: angular, typescript, build, ng-modules, angular.json

I need to have different module for dev mode and prod mode so I think to use the `angular.json` option of fileReplacements creating a `test.module.ts` and `test.module.prod.ts`.
Then I add the following to the `angular.json` configuration:

```json
{
    "replace": "src/app/test/test.module.ts",
    "with": "src/app/test/test.module.prod.ts"
}
```

But in this way I have the error `the Component 'Test1Component' is declared by more than one NgModule.` and this for all component declared in `TestModule`.

There is a workaround for this issue?

Comment: is it a lint issue? if yes, just add ignore comment. if no - you could tune tsconfig to exclude all non related things from compilation and I think angular would agree with that

Comment: I try to add to tsconfig in exclude section "src/app/test/test.module.prod.ts" but the error doesn't disappear. ```TestComponent is declared by more than one NgModule.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap all the components that are common for both modules into a third module and export them. Then import this module into your test modules. Something like this

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [Test1Component],
    exports: [Test1Component],
})
export class TestCommonModule {}

// your test.module.ts
@NgModule({
    imports: [TestCommonModule]
})
export class TestModule {}

// your test.prod.module.ts
@NgModule({
    imports: [TestCommonModule]
})
export class TestProdModule {}
```

Or you can just keep one module and configure it based on imported environment.ts and put this file into the file replacements. This would be even better. Look at this: https://angular.io/guide/build